# How do i use XCOPY with spaces in both paths, even with quotes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to create a batch file that copies files from one path to another, using several xcopy commands. However, the batch script fails because Xcopy apparently has the wrong number of parameters.

I believe the reason is that it thinks the spaces in my folder paths are separating parameters- but I do not know why it is doing this because I have made sure that both the source and destination paths are surrounded with double-quotes.

for example, I run this command in my batch script:

```
c:/windows/system32/xcopy.exe "H:\some path with spaces\myfile.txt" "H:\some path with spaces\a_different_folder\myfile.txt" /Y
```

and it outputs this:

```
Invalid number of parameters
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there is a workaround?
I have also tried using the standard copy command, but that ends up saying the system cannot find the path specified (which isn't true, as my batch file is actually generated by a script that uses the paths of files that are guaranteed to exist)

Comment: `"H:\some path with spaces\a_different_folder\myfile.txt"` is not a destination, `"H:\some path with spaces\a_different_folder\ ` however is! As a side note, this is a Windows system, so please use the correct path separators, `c:\windows\system32\xcopy.exe`, not `c:/windows/system32/xcopy.exe`.

Comment: @Compo even with this change, the same failure occurs.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth changing prefixing the command with `echo ` so instead of executing the command it prints it out - can help with diagnosing tricky stuff such as quotemarks etc.  Obviously it won't *do* anything, but it might show up what's wrong with it.  You can then copy / paste the command and see what it does in the shell, outside of the batch script.

Comment: @GregHNZI have followed this advice but the same failure occurs in cmd. i have verified, the quotes are still correct.

Comment: It is your path to xcopy. It is wrong. It is why you are getting the message. `C:` is a valid command. It will choose a valid command over fixing unix's paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Mark said:

It is your path to xcopy. It is wrong. It is why you are getting the message. C: is a valid command. It will choose a valid command over fixing unix's paths